# Pass React components as part of an array of other data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the correct way to pass React components as part of an array?

I want to pass this data to multiple menu components. Both Icon components accept props which will also need to be passed:

```
import IconAbout from "./icons/about";
import IconContact from "./icons/contact";

const links: { text: string; icon: any }[] = [
  { text: "Contact", icon: IconContact },
  { text: "About", icon: IconAbout },
];
```

Usage:

```
  {links.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        <p>{item.text}</p>
        <item.icon isDark={true} />
      </>
    );
  })}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option for your situation

```
import IconAbout from "./icons/about";
import IconContact from "./icons/contact";

const links = [
  { text: "Contact", icon: <IconContact isDark={true}/> },
  { text: "About", icon: <IconAbout isDark={true}/> },
];
```

```
  {links.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        <p>{item.text}</p>
        {item.icon}
      </>
    );
  })}
```

---

Demo:

[image]

[image: Edit billowing-glade-zr183]

Comment: Im getting a TypeScript error: "TS2749: 'IconContact' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here." and a Unexpected token error and my app stops compiling.

Comment: @Evanss Did you write it on the type? Kindly check the updated demo would be appreciated